# Увеличить скорость компиляции sass

Tags: sass

Использую на проекте *scss*. Столкнулся с проблемой: если разбить код на много маленьких файлов и установить между ними зависимости с помощью `@import`, то время компиляции *scss* в *css* сильно увеличивается и достигает от одной до двух минут, что жутко неудобно.

Решение, которое мне не нравится: Удалить зависимости в файлах и вынести их в отдельный файл (например `main.scss`). Такое решение очень сильно усложняет разработку: например, если мне необходимо создать два файла `app1.scss` и `app2.scss`, которые импортируют `my-component.scss`, то приходится в файлах `app#.scss` указывать все зависимости `my-component.scss`, потому что `my-component.scss` не может содержать зависимостей.

Вопрос: Как ускорить компиляцию *sass* и оставить зависимости между *scss* файлами? (возможно есть какая-то *тулза*, которая опримизирует импорты, или другой компилятор *sass*).

Comment: какую реализацию компилятора используете? Если ruby версию, то попробуйте [libsass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass), он написан на C и работает на порядок быстрее.

Comment: использую [gulp-sass](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) который использует [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) ну а тот в свою очередь использует, предложенную вами, библиотеку [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass)

Comment: Нашли ли Вы ответ на свой вопрос? Столкнулся с той же проблемой.

Comment: @pepel_xD К сожалению нет

Comment: @Kirill Ermolov, есть некоторые идеи, но реализация еще сильно хромает, наберите мне в скайп traveler1056  может вместе что и придумаем.